# htaccess two different parameter amounts

Tags: php, .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting

I have this small htaccess code that should rewrite my urls:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png||ttf|woff)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/event/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ event.php?license=$1&eventID=$2&eventTitle=$3&eventDay=$4 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/event/(.*)/(.*)$ event.php?license=$1&eventID=$2&eventTitle=$3 [NC]
```

when my URL is like this:
http://localhost/license/event/1/name-of-event
it works like a charm.

Though when my url is like this:
http://localhost/license/event/1/name-of-event/1
somehow the value of parameter license is not actually license but 'event.php'

So when I click a link that is generated like this:

```
<?php
echo "<a href='{$_GET['license']}/event/{$_GET['eventID']}/{$_GET['eventTitle']}/{$_GET['eventDay}'>link</a>";

?>
```

will actually direct to http://localhost/event.php/event/1/name-of-event/1
instead of http://localhost/license/event/1/name-of-event/1

I'm not a star in htaccess and I'd like to become better but I have a hard time understanding what is going wrong.